# Python requests library is not working, while cURL is working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, jwt, microsoft-graph-api

I need to retrieve a JWT (JSON Web Token) from a Microsoft API using Python (check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token) API documentation for Microsoft Graph)

The following Python code using the `requests` library does not work giving HTTP response code 400, however, the equivalent cURL command does work giving back the expected JSON containing the JWT.

Python / `requests` code:

```
tenant = "<MY_FOO_TENANT>"
token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token".format(tenant)
http_headers = {
    'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
http_query_params = {
    "client_id": "<MY_FOO_C_ID>",
    "scope": "<MY_FOO_SCOPE>",
    "client_secret": "<MY_FOO_C_SECRET>",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
}
http_response = requests.post(token_url, params=http_query_params, headers=http_headers)
```

cURL command:

```
curl -v -X POST \
  --data-urlencode 'client_id=<MY_FOO_C_ID>' \
  --data-urlencode 'scope=<MY_FOO_SCOPE>' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_secret=<MY_FOO_C_SECRET>' \
  --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<MY_FOO_TENANT>/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

From the verbose output of the `requests` library I can see that it is URL encoding all those HTTP query parameters, so I tend to think that should not be the problem.

- what's wrong with the Python implementation?
- how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should pass `http_query_params` as `data` instead of `params`. try the following code:

```
tenant = "<MY_FOO_TENANT>"
token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token".format(tenant)
http_headers = {
    'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
http_body = {
    "client_id": "<MY_FOO_C_ID>",
    "scope": "<MY_FOO_SCOPE>",
    "client_secret": "<MY_FOO_C_SECRET>",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
}
http_response = requests.post(token_url, data=http_body, headers=http_headers)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks that helps and it works. However this means that `http_query_params` is not really HTTP query params (`?xxx=yyy&aaa=bbb`), but instead it's the HTTP request body, right? And the reason it works in `cURL` is due to the fact that `--data-urlencode` is not actually encoding HTTP query parameters, but it's URL encoding HTTP request body due to the "form header format" (HTTP header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), right?

Comment: Hmmm, I see so basically you don’t want it to be in the body of the request but in the URL?

Comment: I think I was tricked by that "form header" combined with my misunderstanding of cURL `--data-urlencode`. Your suggestion works, and looking at the `requests` docs it seems the `data=` parameter is for HTTP bodies. So basically the example in the Microsoft documentation is a bit misleading when presenting those key/value pairs as (URL encoded) HTTP query parameters.

Comment: Oh great! So does my code solve your issue? Or you have any other problems that you are facing now?

Comment: Yes, I would just add a mention that `http_query_params` should be renamed to `http_body` and (AFAIK) this probably works as HTTP body because of the HTTP header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Yes definitely, I’ll do the edit right alway (just didn’t want to mess with the naming as I was afraid that you might have been using http_query_params somewhere else in your code). If you could mark this answer as solved that would be very much appreciated :)